# How to bind div's width to a model in angular 2.0?

Tags: html, css, angular

How to bind the width property of an element to the model then from model to another dev?

```
<div [width1]="style.width.px">
<div [style.width.px]="width2">

export class MyComponent
{
 width1: number;
 width2: number = width1 - 30;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say :

```
<div #width1>
<div [style.width.px]="width2">

export class MyComponent
{
width1: number;
 @ViewChild('width1') width1;


 ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.width2  = this.width1.nativeElement. width - 30;

  }
}
```

Comment: width1 is undefined in ngAfterViewInit()